# Value Next of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I'm trying to save `json_data` from server to sqlite, but i'm getting the error

```
Value Next of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Here is my json : [My Json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/14nsyv/?pretty=1)

And here is my java code :

```
String json_data = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json_data);
JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject("Next");
JSONArray Jarray  = object1.getJSONArray("Days");
for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
    dbHelper.putStationsInformation((Jasonobject),sqLiteDatabase);
}
dbHelper.close();
```

I know this code looks weird but please help me do this.

Comment: `JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject("Next");` - really ?

Comment: sometimes I don't understand how people get to the point where they get a response from a server but don't understand how an object-mapping structure works or how to use the damn debugger.

Answer (score 2):

> "Value Next of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   JSONArray".

Rectify **`getJSONObject`** section.

**Dont**

```
 JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject("Next");
```

**Do**

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_data );
 JSONObject _jsonOBJ = obj.getJSONObject("Next");
 JSONArray Jarray  = _jsonOBJ .getJSONArray("Days");
 for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
 {
     JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     dbHelper.putStationsInformation((Jasonobject),sqLiteDatabase);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch `Next` `jsonobject` instead of creating it here with a single `String` like

`new JSONObject("Next");` , so fetch it from response `object` like

```
JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("Next");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject result_obj= new JSONObject(result.toString());
 JSONObject result_array= result_obj.getJSONObject("Next");
 JSONArray array_values = result_array.getJSONArray("Days");
 for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
 {
     JSONObject plan = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
      plan.getString("Day");
      for(int j=0;j<plan.lenght();j++){


       }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Parse the "Next" object from the json provided. You have created a new JSONObject that was the mistake.

```
  try {
        String json_data = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json_data);
        JSONObject object1 =object.getJSONObject("Next");
        JSONArray Jarray  = object1.getJSONArray("Days");
        for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            dbHelper.putStationsInformation((Jasonobject),sqLiteDatabase);
            dbHelper.close();

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new JSONObject("Next")which means you are converting a string "Next" into a JSONObject.
Rectify to this:

```
String json_data = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json_data);
JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("Next");
```